# i have a problem about pytube and tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, urllib3, pytube

I'm getting this error and I couldn't find the solution

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fetta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fetta\PycharmProjects\KofteTubeV2\main.py", line 16, in Downloader
    video = url.streams.get_highest_resolution()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fetta\PycharmProjects\KofteTubeV2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 295, in streams
    self.check_availability()
  File "C:\Users\fetta\PycharmProjects\KofteTubeV2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 210, in check_availability
    status, messages = extract.playability_status(self.watch_html)
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fetta\PycharmProjects\KofteTubeV2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 102, in watch_html
    self._watch_html = request.get(url=self.watch_url)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fetta\PycharmProjects\KofteTubeV2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 53, in get
    response = _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers, timeout=timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fetta\PycharmProjects\KofteTubeV2\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 37, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fetta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 212, in urlopen
    _opener = opener = build_opener()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fetta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 593, in build_opener
    opener.add_handler(klass())
                       ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\fetta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1386, in __init__
    context = http.client._create_https_context(http_version)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'http.client' has no attribute '_create_https_context'
```

I'm waiting for my code to download video, audio and playlist from youtube but it didn't work

```
from tkinter import *
import pytube

kof = Tk()
kof.geometry('600x400')
kof.title("Kofte Youtube | Video & Sound & Playlist | Downloader")

Label(kof, text='Youtube Video Downloader', font='arial 20 bold').pack()

link = StringVar()
Label(kof, text='Link Here:', font='arial 15 bold').pack()
Entry(kof, width=70, textvariable=link).pack()

def Downloader():
    url = pytube.YouTube(str(link.get()))
    video = url.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    video.download()
    Label(kof, text='Video Downloaded', font="arial 15").place(x=180, y=210)


def Sounder():
    url = pytube.YouTube(str(link.get()))
    video = url.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    video.download()
    Label(kof, text='Video Downloaded', font="arial 15").place(x=180, y=210)


def Playlister():
    url = pytube.YouTube(str(link.get()))
    video = url.streams.first()
    video.download()
    Label(kof, text='Playlist Downloaded', font="arial 15").place(x=180, y=210)


Button(kof, text="Downloader", font="arial 10 bold", padx=2, command=Downloader).pack()
Button(kof, text="Sounder", font="arial 10 bold", padx=2, command=Sounder).pack()
Button(kof, text="Playlister", font="arial 10 bold", padx=2, command=Playlister).pack()
kof.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is pretty well documented here and on GitHub that the YouTube API has changed breaking pytube. The developers are aware of the issue and have a fix; however, a new release (> 15.0.0) has not yet been released. This seems to be a common occurrence